# WPF MessageBox Appearing Twice

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using following code for showing a MessageBox with ok and cancel button. When I click any button same message box appears again. Is there any problem in this code?

```
        string messageBoxText = "Uploading Data";
        string caption = "Upload Data";
        MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;                
        // Display message box
        MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
        MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
        if (res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
           count++;              
        }
```

Comment: you jsut need to comment first MessageBox.Show line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are calling `MessageBox.Show` two times...

```
string messageBoxText = "Uploading Data";
    string caption = "Upload Data";
    MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;                
    // Display message box
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon); //**Comment this line**
    MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
    if (res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
       count++;              
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling message box twice via `MessageBox.Show`. You might want to remove the first

```
MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
```